Dremio Kubernetes: Zookeeper fails to connect to '/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/2181'
I am attempting to deploy dremio onto Kubernetes (k8s version 1.30.2) with the helm charts from the GitHub (charts/dremio_v2), but I am encountering an issue in which one of the zookeeper pods fails to start, preventing other service from starting correctly. The output of kubectl get pods is shown below.
NAME                READY   STATUS             RESTARTS          AGE
dremio-executor-0   0/1     Init:2/3           0                 23h
dremio-executor-1   1/1     Running            0                 23h
dremio-executor-2   0/1     Init:2/3           0                 23h
dremio-master-0     1/1     Running            0                 23h
zk-0                0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   453 (3m36s ago)   23h
zk-1                1/1     Running            0                 23h
zk-2                1/1     Running            0                 23h

Inspecting the failing node with kubectl logs zk-0 shows nothing notable.
ZOO_MY_ID=1
ZOO_SERVERS=server.1=zk-0.zk-hs.default.svc.cluster.local:2888:3888;2181 server.2=zk-1.zk-hs.default.svc.cluster.local:2888:3888;2181 server.3=zk-2.zk-hs.default.svc.cluster.local:2888:3888;2181
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /conf/zoo.cfg
2024-07-10 14:43:06,852 [myid:] - INFO  [main:o.a.z.s.q.QuorumPeerConfig@177] - Reading configuration from: /conf/zoo.cfg
2024-07-10 14:43:06,856 [myid:] - INFO  [main:o.a.z.s.q.QuorumPeerConfig@431] - clientPort is not set
2024-07-10 14:43:06,856 [myid:] - INFO  [main:o.a.z.s.q.QuorumPeerConfig@444] - secureClientPort is not set
2024-07-10 14:43:06,856 [myid:] - INFO  [main:o.a.z.s.q.QuorumPeerConfig@460] - observerMasterPort is not set
2024-07-10 14:43:06,856 [myid:] - INFO  [main:o.a.z.s.q.QuorumPeerConfig@477] - metricsProvider.className is org.apache.zookeeper.metrics.impl.DefaultMetricsProvider

However, kubectl describe pod zk-0 seems to give some insight into the error under the Events section.
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                   From     Message
  ----     ------     ----                  ----     -------
  Warning  Unhealthy  27m (x1343 over 24h)  kubelet  Liveness probe failed: /bin/bash: connect: Connection refused
/bin/bash: line 1: /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/2181: Connection refused
/bin/bash: line 1: 3: Bad file descriptor
/bin/bash: line 1: 3: Bad file descriptor
  Warning  BackOff    7m38s (x5514 over 23h)  kubelet  Back-off restarting failed container kubernetes-zookeeper in pod zk-0_default(bf558817-9303-4718-b6da-117dff8b48c7)
  Warning  Unhealthy  2m36s (x1818 over 24h)  kubelet  Readiness probe failed: /bin/bash: connect: Connection refused
/bin/bash: line 1: /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/2181: Connection refused
/bin/bash: line 1: 3: Bad file descriptor
/bin/bash: line 1: 3: Bad file descriptor

This seems to be in reference to the readiness check (/bin/bash -c [ "$(echo ruok | (exec 3<>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/2181; cat >&3; cat <&3; exec 3<&-))" == "imok" ]] delay=10s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3). However, the logs reveal no errors with the zookeeper pod, so it is unclear to me why it would fail the readiness check. Is it possible that the readiness check is restarting the pod before it has had time to fully initialize? Or is it more likely that the pod is hanging somewhere in startup?
If anyone can advise me on how to debug this, I would be very grateful.
